# user info command works only witout a mention

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i have a problem with my code for the command userinfo it works witout a mantion but not wen a mention somoen

wenn i run the code without a mention it works but wenn i try to test it with a user mentiond the code dosent give me an error it just ignors it

this is the code

```
  if (message.content === prefix + 'userinfo') {
    if (message.mentions.users.size) {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${message.mentions.users.first().tag}`)
        .setColor("03fc94")
        .setThumbnail(message.mentions.users.first().avatarURL())
        .addFields(
          { name: 'ID', value: `${message.mentions.users.first().id}`, inline: true }, 
          { name: 'Username', value: `${message.mentions.users.first().username}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Discriminator', value: `${message.mentions.users.first().discriminator}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Bot', value: `${message.mentions.users.first().bot}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Created At', value: `${message.mentions.users.first().createdAt}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Roles', value: `${message.mentions.users.first().roles.cache.map(r => r.name).join(', ')}`, inline: true },
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('');
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
    } else {
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${message.author.tag}`)
        .setColor("03fc94")
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
        .addFields(
          { name: 'ID', value: `${message.author.id}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Discriminator', value: `${message.author.discriminator}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'roles', value: `${message.member.roles.cache.map(r => r.name).join(', ')}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Joined', value: `${message.member.joinedAt}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Created', value: `${message.author.createdAt}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Is Bot', value: `${message.author.bot}`, inline: true },
          { name: 'Is Owner', value: `${message.author.id === owner}`, inline: true },
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('');
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
    }
  }
}); ` ` `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `message.mentions.users.size` you can use `message.mentions.members.first()`. To get this command works, you can also use `if() {} else if() {}` statement. For example:

```
if(!args[0]) {
   //This is the part for non-mentioned members. 
} else if(args[0]) {
   //This is the part for mentioned members.
}
```

You can also use `if() {} else {}` statement.

```
if(!args[0]) {
   //This is the part for non-mentioned members.
} else {
   //This is the part for mentioned members.
}
```

In addition:

```
 if(!args[0]) {
   const author = message.author.id //or you can do message.author also
   //Then your codes here
} else {
   const member = message.mentions.members.first() //You can use ID's also
   //Then your codes here. 
}
```

To use it on `embed`. This is not the right calling about the member

```
{ name: 'ID', value: `${message.mentions.users.first().id}`, inline: true },
```

So change it to:

```
{ name: 'ID', value: `${member.user.id}`, inline: true },
```

Comment: now i have the message is not deffind error

`if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.mentions.users.first().tag}`)
      .setColor("03fc94")
      .setThumbnail(message.mentions.users.first().avatarURL())
      .addFields`

Comment: No, If you're using `if(!args[0]) {} else {}` statement, delete your recent `if else` statement. **re-code** your command file.

Comment: like this?

`if(!args[0]) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.author.tag}`)
      .setColor("03fc94")
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())`

Comment: Yes, just like that, same with `else` statement

Comment: ok now i just have the error [ message is not defined ] wenn i start the bot,

Comment: i send the code in the chat

Comment: its this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244828/discussion-between-nemson-and-acesyyy